# how to read and process utf-8 characters in one char in c from the file

Tags: c, utf-8

how i can to read and process utf-8 characters in one char in c from the file
this is my code

```
FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    char *code;
    size_t n = 0;
    if (file == NULL) return NULL;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long f_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    code = malloc(f_size);
    char a,b;
    while (!feof(file)) {
        fscanf(file, "%c", &a);
        code[n++] = a;
       // i want to modify "a" (current char) in here
    }
    code[n] = '\0';
```

this is file content

> ~”م‘‎iاk·¶;R0ثp9´
>   -پ‘“گAéI‚sہئzOU,HدلKŒ©َض†ُ­ ت6‘گA=…*¢¢³qد4â9àr}h*w O‍Uجy.4a³‎M;£´`د$r(q¸Œçً£F 6pG|ںJr(TîsشR

Comment: The `char` type can hold numbers 0 to 255 or -128 to 127. To properly process Unicode text you need a type capable of holding characters 0 to 1114111. Surrogate pairs do save a little, allowing you to limit youself to characters 0 to 65535.

Comment: You're reading one byte at a time, and UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding. You're going to be pretty limited in how you can modify the characters without trying to parse the input as UTF-8. I would try to find a library that lets you read and process UTF-8 text.

Comment: See [while(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/3386109), and [info on how to decode UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Comment: tnx my friend ; what is the library name in c language

Comment: @SiavashUnesi: The file content you have shown in your question is *NOT* UTF-8.  It is not even textual data.  It looks more like binary data instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Chars can commonly hold 255 different values (1 byte), or in other words, just the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table (it could use the extended table if you make it unsigned). For handling UTF-8 characters i would recommend using another type like [wchar_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/) (if a wide character [in your compiler](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/unicode_wchar_t.html) means as an UTF-8), otherwise use [char_32](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/char32_t) if you're using C++11, or a library to deal with your data like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

---

### Edit

This example code explains how to deal with UTF-8 in C. Note that you have to make sure that wchar_t in your compiler can store an UTF-8.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
main() {
    FILE *file=fopen("Testing.txt", "r, ccs=UTF-8");
    wchar_t sentence[100000], ch=1;
    int n=0;
    char*loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("Locale set to: %s\n", loc);
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("Error processing file\n");
    } else {
        while((ch = fgetwc(file)) != 65535){
            /* The end of file value may vary depending of the wchar_t!*/
            /* wprintf(L"%lc", ch); */
            sentence[n]=ch+1; /*Example modification*/
            n++;
                }
    }
    fclose(file);
    file=fopen("Testing.txt", "w, ccs=UTF-8");
    fputws(sentence, file);
    wprintf(L"%ls", sentence);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

- **Your system locale**
  The `char*loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` will help you see your current system locale. Make sure is in UTF-8 if your using linux, if you're using windows then you'll have to [stick to one language](https://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7). This is not a problem if you don't want to print the characters.
- **How to open the file**
  Firstly, I opened it for [reading it as text file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) instead of reading it as binary file. Also I have to open the file using the UTF-8 formating (I think in linux it will be as your locale, so the `ccs=UTF-8` won't be necessary). Even though in windows we're stuck with one language, the file still has to be read in UTF-8.
- **Using compatible functions with the characters**
  For this we'll use the functions inside the [wchar.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/) library (like wprintf and fgetwc). The problem with the other functions is that they are limited to the range of a char, giving the wrong value.

I used as an example this:

> ¿khñà?
> hello
> ~”م‘‎iاk·¶;R0ثp9´ -پ‘“گAéI‚sہئzOU,HدلKŒ©َض†ُ­ ت6‘گA=…¢¢³qد4â9àr}hw O‍Uجy.4a³‎M;£´`د$r(q¸Œçً£F 6pG|ںJr(TîsشR

In the last part of the program It overwrites the file with the acumulated modified string.
You could try changing `sentence[n]=ch+1;` to `sentence[n]=ch;` to check in your original file if it reads and outputs the file correctly (and uncomment the wprintf to check the output).

Comment: tnx my friend
may rewrite above code to **wchar_t** ; 
i change it to  **wchar_t** but result was same as **char** result

Comment: Suggest `char32_t` instead of `wchar_t`.  Else insure `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is set.

Comment: "Chars can only hold from 0 to 255 (1 byte), or in other words, just the ASCII table. " is incorrect on 3 points. 1) The range of `char` is often -128 to 127,  it is implementation defined and matches either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.  2) The range on rare machines is more than 8 bits 3) ASCII is only defined for codes 0 - 127.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and sorry for a novice answer.

Comment: The `ccs=UTF-8` flag is a Microsoft-specific extension of `fopen()` in Visual Studio.  Other vendor implementations of `fopen()` do not have that extension.

Comment: tnxxxx very much my friend "sicalmforgost" ; it work <3